# Selecting both matching Rows from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I am linking two tables and I want matching rows from both tables displayed as separate rows in the output table.

Example:

```
Table 1
1   AAA
2   BBB
3   CCC
4   DDD
5   EEE
```

Table 2;

```
2   WWW
4   XXX
5   YYY
6   ZZZ
7   UUU
```

Output:

```
2   BBB
2   WWW
4   DDD
4   XXX
5   EEE
5   YYY
```

Comment: Hi Waka, I have been trying using the full outer join but the data gets listed in single row.

Comment: What SQL product are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this (combining two sets as one) but the first that comes to mind is to use a `union`statement:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Column1 IN (SELECT Column1 FROM Table2)

UNION ALL -- union all returns all rows including duplicates
          -- union without all returns all but no duplicates

SELECT Column1, Column2 
FROM Table2
WHERE Column1 IN (SELECT Column1 FROM Table1)
ORDER BY Column1, Column2
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4495/1)

In the example above I used `IN`operator with a subquery to determine what rows should be returned in each set; another, and potentially better performing option would be to use joins to limit the members of each set like this:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1

UNION ALL

SELECT Column1, Column2 
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1

ORDER BY Column1, Column2
```

The general concept with the `union` statement is that you form two similar (in that they have the same columns with the same data types) sets and then use the `union`operator to merge them together as one, optionally including duplicate rows by adding`all`to the operator.